# midnight commander freezes on remote file copy over fish/ssh protocol

Tags: ssh, fish, midnight-commander

I'm using midnight commander (mc), version 4.8.1 shipped with Ubuntu. when I try to copy a file from remote ssh server over the fish/ssh protocol, mc freezes at 0%, and I had to terminate it.

I tried to compile the latest mc 4.8.15 from the source code, and run it from the build directory without install it, mc will fails to load the skin, however It surprisingly  succeeds to copy the file. However If I try to install it, and then run it from the installed copy it will freeze again on the ssh copy.

The above might suggest a configuration issue with mc that it cannot well handle.

Answer (score 0):

I use sshfs in midnight commander to copy a lot of files and there a few files where it reliably hangs, usually somewhere in the middle. My guess is that it's due to some magic byte pattern that hangs the connection somehow, maybe some ssh escape sequence that isn't being double escaped.
I've had this issue for many years with many version of mc.

https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3236 claims it's fixed for 4.8.12 for someone, but it's still there in 4.8.17 for me.